# How can I parse numbers from a command line argument into two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, stdio

I'm trying to take two arguments from the command line, a char and an int string of 1's and 0's of x length. I want to check if it's only 5 1's and 0's, if so I'll put them into an array. If it's longer than 5, it will be ten such as 10011 10110; in this case I want to parse the input into two different arrays. The first digit goes to A, the second one goes to B and so on until I have two arrays such as a = 10101, b = 01110.

How can I accomplish this? I've tried a put(c) until EOF while loop but can't seem to get anything out of it. Below is my entire program which will eventually put the arrays into LLL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodeA {
  int dork; 
  struct nodeA * next;
};

typedef struct nodeA d1;

struct nodeB {
  int dork;
  struct nodeB * next;
};

typedef struct nodeB d2;

struct mathOp {
  char operation;
  struct mathOp * next;
};

typedef struct mathOp dorkOp;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char a;
  int b;    

  d1 * curr = NULL, * head = NULL;
  dorkOp * curr3 = NULL, * head3 = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  int aA[8] = {0};
  int aB[8] = {0};
  int tempA, tempB;

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Program takes <char> <int>\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  a = atoi (argv[1]);
  b = atoi (argv[2]);

  printf("Test call a = %c, b = %d \n", a, b);

  tempA = b;
  tempB = b;

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    curr3 = (dorkOp *)malloc(sizeof(dorkOp));
    curr3->operation = a;
    curr3->next = head3;
    head = curr;
  }

  while (curr3) {
    printf("%c\n", curr3->operation);
    curr3 = curr3->next;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    curr = (d1 *)malloc(sizeof(d1));
    curr->dork = tempA;
    curr->next = head;
    head = curr;
  }

  while (curr) {
    printf("%d\n", curr->dork);
    curr = curr->next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most of your code seems to bear no relation to your question. Just check `argv[1][0]`, `argv[1][1]`, and such, to check if they equal `'1'` or `'0'`, and if so, copy them into your array.

Comment: I cannot see how you convert the input 10011 10110 into the two values a = 10101, b = 01110. As yet, your problem is incompletely described (at best — at worst, completely inscrutable). As Paul Griffiths pointed out, most of the code is unrelated to your problem; the structure types are not required to solve a problem of copying a transformed argument into one or more arrays. I think you should delete this question temporarily, work out how to ask it with two sample inputs (one short, one long), the corresponding outputs, and an explanation of how you got the outputs. Then undelete it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I believe the transformation logic is that `a[]` would end up consisting of `input[0]`, `input[2]`, `input[4]`, and so on, and `b[]` would end up consisting of `input[1]`, `input[3]`, etc.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: OK — that makes sense if we treat a = 10101 as a shorthand for something like: `a[] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };` (which is the result that's achieved, not the way you'd achieve it).  I'm still not clear how the program would be invoked: `./a.out X "10011 10110"`, or what.  And is the length strictly 5 or 11 (or is the space omitted, so it is 5 or 10)?  What should the program do when given erroneous input (such as `X` as the character, which is converted to an `int` by `atoi()`)?  But, within limits, what you say makes sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Agreed, and I'm slightly mystified by the `putc(c)` attempt.

Comment: Yes, `putc(c)` until EOF is also mysterious — somewhat like a red herring, methinks.  Standard I/O, even if `getc()` is intended, shouldn't be used to parse command line arguments.  (`sscanf()` et al might be relevant, but using either `putc()` or `getc()` is … non-obvious, shall we say?)

Comment: [ a.out a 1000110001 ] <-- This is an example invoke of the program.  I'm trying to figure out how to take the string of numbers and put them into two different arrays.  5 numbers go into array a, 5 into array b in the form of parsing.

Answer (score 1):

I did not see a question to answer, so here is the OPs code, with my comments,  prefixed by '`<--`' and following line indentation.

1. Good indentation helps wonderfully for readability,
      so I have indented the code
      (and modified some struct and variable definitions
       to align with good coding practice)

Here are the compile results:

```
50:16: warning: variable 'tempB' set but not used
48:9: warning: unused variable 'aB'
47:9: warning: unused variable 'aA'
```

I have not fixed any of these items in the following code.
As an aside, why post code that does not compile?

BTW: this code, supplied by the OP, does none of the actions listed in the OP's remarks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodeA
{
    int dork;
    struct nodeA * next;
};

typedef struct nodeA d1;

struct nodeB
{
    int dork;
    struct nodeB * next;
};

typedef struct nodeB d2;

struct mathOp
{
    char operation;
    struct mathOp * next;
};

typedef struct mathOp dorkOp;


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char a;
    int b;
    d1 * curr = NULL;
    d1 * head = NULL;

    //d2 * curr2 = NULL;
    //d2 * head2 = NULL;

    dorkOp * curr3 = NULL;
    dorkOp * head3 = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    //int array[10] = {0};

    int aA[8] = {0};
    int aB[8] = {0};

    int tempA;
    int tempB;


    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Program takes <char> <int>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    a = atoi (argv[1]);  
    // <-- argv[1] is expected to be a char, 
    //     and 'a' is defined as a char
    //     so the result of atoi() will be 0
    //     and 'a = 0' probably will not yield anything useful 

    b = atoi (argv[2]); 
    // <-- argv[2] is a null terminated string of 1s and 0s, 
    //     which would be easy to parse, so why the conversion? 

    printf("Test call a = %c, b = %d \n", a, b); 
    // <-- 'a' is an unprintable char, so the output is doubtful

    tempA = b;  // <-- shouldn't this be: tempA = a;
    tempB = b;

    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)  
    // <-- waste of a 'for' because only room for one dorkOp 
    //     and the 'for' will only execute once
    //     suggest removing the 'for' but not the enclosed code block
    {
        curr3 = (dorkOp *)malloc(sizeof(dorkOp));
        // <-- in C, casting the returned value from malloc is 
        //     bad programming practice, for several reasons
        // <-- the returned value from malloc() needs to be checked
        //     to assure successful operation
        //     if not successful, 
        //     then, following lines are dereferencing an offset from 0
        //           which will result in a seg fault event
        curr3->operation = a;
        // <-- 'a' contains 0x00, (see above comment about setting 'a')
        //     so curr3->operation now contains 0x00
        curr3->next = head3; 
        // <-- head3 contains NULL
        //     so this line places NULL in curr3->next
        head = curr;  
        // <-- curr AND head are already both ptrs containing NULL
        //     so this line has no effect
    }

    while(curr3)
    {
        printf("%c\n", curr3->operation);
        // <-- curr3->operation was (see above) set to 0x00
        //     which is a non-printable char
        //     so the displayed output is in doubt
        curr3 = curr3->next;
        // <-- curr3, on the first pass through this loop is set to NULL
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    // <-- waste of a 'for' because only room for one d1 
    //     and the 'for' will only execute once
    //     suggest removing the 'for' but not the enclosed code block
    {
        curr = (d1 *)malloc(sizeof(d1));
        // <-- in C, casting the returned value from malloc is 
        //     bad programming practice, for several reasons
        // <-- the code needs to check the returned value from malloc
        //     to assure a successful operation
        //     if not successful
        //     then, the following code will be dereferencing from address 0
        //           which will result in a seg fault event
        curr->dork = tempA;
        curr->next = head;
        // <-- head contains NULL so now curr-> contains NULL
        head = curr; 
    }

    // <-- following loop will only execute once
    //     so why make it a loop?
    while(curr)
    {
        printf("%d\n", curr->dork);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return 0;
}  // end function: main
```

Comment: I've been told to post my entire program before, so I'm just in the habit of doing so.  The code does compile.  The structs will be used later, after I figure out how to read the argv[1] argument into two separate arrays depending on the input.

Comment: The input is five ints, 1 or 0.  e.g. 10001.  It can also be ten ints, e.g. 1000110001.  When reading an input into an array I need to know if its 5 or ten.  If its ten I need to parse the numbers, the first digit goes to array a, the 2nd goes to array b, the 3rd goes to array a and so on.

Comment: "b = atoi (argv[2]); 
    // <-- argv[2] is a null terminated string of 1s and 0s, 
    //     which would be easy to parse, so why the conversion? "              The parsing problem of b into two arrays is exactly what I'm attempting to solve. Later, I will put the formed arrays into linear linked lists.

Comment: If you think the code compiles, then you have many, if not most of the compiler warnings disabled.  I did list, in my answer, three items that stop this code from being a successful compile.  I.E. warnings are not a pat-on-the-back about how good the code is.  Rather they are a heads up about how bad the code is.